# Sequelize: full text search using symbol based operators

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, full-text-search

So I'm trying to implement postgresql full text search through Sequelize 3 but there're a few problems including that, I couldn't add text search functions in current `where` clause:

```
where: {
    published: true,
    and: where(
      fn("tsmatch",
        col("tokens"),
        fn("plainto_tsquery", query),
      ),
      true,
    )
},
```

I know we can use raw sql statement but the problem is that existing implementation is based on Sequelize operators and that's what Sequelize recommends for security.
Found a good resource for adding and reusing a function for it [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1580#issuecomment-336035877) but am stuck in combining it with other query params.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've ended up using `where` clause again:

```
where: {
    published: true,
    where: where(
      fn("tsmatch",
        col("textTokens"),
        fn("plainto_tsquery", text),
      ),
      true,
    )
},
```

Hope this would help others facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize version 6.5.0+ supports the `TSVECTOR` datatype and `Op.match`:

```js
Model.findAll({
  where: { 
    textTokens: { [Op.match]: sequelize.fn('to_tsquery', query) }
  }
})
```

Comment: How would you escape the query before passing it in the where clause?